# Forge Autodesk : markup dragging event trigger

Tags: autodesk-forge

I created a .net core application that loads forge viewer,
I am loading markups from database (inserted manually),
now I need to insert/update markups when the markup is created or updated.
I am trying to handle the event EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING, but its not being trigger when I create or drag markups.

here is my code:

```
var options = {
                env: 'AutodeskProduction',
                api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
                getAccessToken: function (onTokenReady) {
                    var token = result;
                    var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
                    onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
                }
            };
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
            var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv , config3d);
            var startedCode = viewer.start();
            if (startedCode > 0) {
                console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
                return;
            }
            console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
            var documentId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
            function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
                var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
                viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then(function (markupsExt) {
                    markup = markupsExt;
                    
                    const namespace = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core;                         
                    markup.addEventListener(namespace.EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING, function (ev) {
                        console.log(ev.markup);
                        selectedmarkup = ev.markup;
                        $(".TypeMarkup").text(selectedmarkup.type);
                        $(".IDMarkup").text(selectedmarkup.id);
                    });
                   
                });
               
            }
            function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
                console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the `EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING` event is not triggered anymore. I will double-check with the viewer engineering team to see why.

In the meantimme I'd suggest using the `EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_START` and `EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_END` events which *are* triggered whenever a markup is being modified.

Comment: inside the loadextension i added this:
markup.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_START, function (ev) {
                            alert("event started!!!!");
                        });