# Some MarkupsCore event not firing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

The event **EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING** for MarkupsCore, as documented [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/markupscore/#event-markup-dragging) is not working when I do  `ext.addEventListener('EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING', function(ev){console.log('run')});`

I have other events working such as **EVENT_EDITMODE_CHANGED** and **EVENT_MARKUP_SELECTED** & **EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_START**. But the dragging event doesn't work, it seems completely broken.

Am I doing somehting wrong here? I am trying to update my server every time a markups is moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63992921,

The EVENT_MARKUP_DRAGGING is no longer triggered, and our engineering team confirmed it's a legacy.

So, we'd suggest using the EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_START and EVENT_EDITFRAME_EDITION_END events, which are triggered whenever a markup is being modified.